# Where is the controller in Angular 7 as it follows mvc architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

According to my knowledge angular follows mvc architecture as i can see in the components there is .ts file(model) and .html file(view) but where is the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using the Angular framework, it is necessary to understand a few basic terms which will constitue the application you create.

`Component`: A component is a resuable code, which is capable of performing a set of functions or providing a view based on certain inputs. These inputs are optional. The component may additionally `emit` events in order to inform its parent component of the changes which might have taken place due to a particular action such as a `click`.

I am not too Keen on using MVC notation but if we were to strictly choose,

**the template would represent the View, class is the Controller & the Service (when it used to retrieve data) is the model.**

Because Angular is a client side framework, the MVC pattern Angular follows may be called as MVVC (Model, View, View Controller).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing controller in angular.

It's only have component, view, model, services

1. Component: Will play the role of the controller since it handle
   logic for the template
2. Template: Will handle the role view to display the data
3. Model: Entity model will play the role model in your app
4. Services: To handle logic for you making http request or doing some side effect in your code

Comment: Hello Expert thanks for answering the question may i know which design pattern does angular follows is it mvc or mvvm?

Comment: Angular follow MVVM pattern but you can think component as Controller because it handle logic for your app

Comment: what is AppModule role here?

Comment: AppModule is the main module too bootstrap the application

Comment: what are the files in angular that plays a mvvm role?

Comment: You can read [this](https://medium.com/ngx-rocket/the-missing-introduction-to-angular-and-modern-design-patterns-43e8815c2801)

Answer (score 0):

.ts is just the file extension which represents typescript file.
model-name.model.ts is the the common way of naming model. Similarly, component-name.component.ts is for component, component-name.component.html for view and service-name.service.ts for service.
Finally, as the earlier comment says, you can't directly relate MVC with angular architecture.